# NSURLERRORDOMAIN--1012E: (null) on Bluemix

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-cloud

I am trying to connect Bluemix remote DB as the following:

```
IMFDataManager.sharedInstance().remoteStore("people", completionHandler: { (store:CDTStore!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        var query:CDTCloudantQuery = CDTCloudantQuery(dataType: "Person")

        store.performQuery(query, completionHandler: { (results:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            var myData = results as! [Person]
            println(myData.count)
        })
    })
```

For some reason I get the following error message.

I have checked the documentation and couldn't find any relevant about authentication.

```
2015-06-01 19:05:38.672 helloBluemix[34398:2621801] [INFO] [IMFData] Authorization failure.  Http status 401 received on request to https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/5fc5cfd9-73db-432b-a1f5-3f2824e1c5ec/peoples/_find
2015-06-01 19:05:38.676 helloBluemix[34398:2621799] [ERROR] [IMFData] Error occured during query.  URL: https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/5fc5cfd9-73db-432b-a1f5-3f2824e1c5ec/peoples/_find.  queryJSON: {
    selector =     {
        "@datatype" = Person;
    };
} NSURLERRORDOMAIN--1012E: (null)
```

Comment: Hi, could you please give more details about the error, about the service you are trying to use

Comment: Hi, sorry, I stopped working on this and meanwhile the trial period was over. Honestly, I lost interest totally due to the lack of documentation.

Comment: If you can provide some more information about the error, we can fix anything that is lacking in the documentation.

Comment: Bill, thank you. I faced this issue almost 4 months ago. That time I asked one of the Bluemix developer on Twitter to check this issue. Sorry, I can repeat only myself, I don't intend to work on this project in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

I did some changes to my code but could not think of something I changed in the Bluemix interaction code... 
When I previously had authorization errors I was able to fix it by adjusting the access rights for the database in the "Cloudant Dashboard". However, it is now set to "Read" and "Write" for "Everybody else", so that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error before I set user permissions on my `IMFDataManager` object after I got a reference to it:

```
IMFDataManager *manager = [IMFDataManager sharedInstance];
[manager remoteStore:@"<your_db_name>" completionHandler:^(CDTStore *store, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"there was an error fetching or creating the remote store");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"remote store success");
        [manager setCurrentUserPermissions:DB_ACCESS_GROUP_MEMBERS forStoreName:@"<your_db_name>" completionHander:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error setting permissions");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"set permissions successfully");
            }
            }];
        }
}];
```